# What defines strscpy in C?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, strcpy, strlcpy

From this [video on youtube by Kees Cook from 
linux.conf.au 2019](https://youtu.be/FY9SbqTO5GQ?t=1277) he mentions `strscpy` as being preferred but generally doing what users want (less `NUL`-padding). However, he doesn't say what defines this (spec or header),

Slide from the video,

[image: strscpy slide]

I can't find `strscpy()` with `man`

```
$ for i in strcpy strlcpy strscpy; do man -w $i; done;
/usr/share/man/man3/strcpy.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/strlcpy.3bsd.gz
No manual entry for strscpy
```

Comment: https://mafford.com/text/the-many-ways-to-copy-a-string-in-c/

Comment: `strscpy()` it not part of C, nor of POSIX. It is an extension. Using it make the code unportable.

Comment: strscpy does its thing safely, but I don't think silent truncation is what users generally want. It is nit standard anyway. The standard (but optional and not supported by glibc) function that does the same thing is strcpy_s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the [linux source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/linux/string.h#L29), not in the standard library.  [Online man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/linux-manual-4.8/strscpy.9.en.html)

Comment: Shoulf we expect it to be added into GLibc?

Comment: @SomeName: Not all functions, provided in the Linux kernel, are really needed for user-space programs. And, in my opinion, `strscpy` is one of them: it very cares about non-trusted strings, which may come from the user space (and shouldn't make the kernel to crash in any case), but this feature is not so crucial for user-space programs. See also [this reasoning](https://mafford.com/text/the-many-ways-to-copy-a-string-in-c/) about some functions added to the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there isn't any library that provides this function (AFAIK), you can write it yourself.  I'm sure it can be optimized, but a very simple definition using GNU C11 for it is this one, which I use:

```
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/string/strcpy/strscpy.h */


#include <stddef.h>


__attribute__((nonnull))
ptrdiff_t strscpy       (char dest[restrict /*size*/],
                         const char src[restrict /*size*/],
                         ptrdiff_t size);
```

```
#include "libalx/base/string/strcpy/strscpy.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>


ptrdiff_t strscpy       (char dest[restrict /*size*/],
                         const char src[restrict /*size*/],
                         ptrdiff_t size)
{
        ptrdiff_t   len;

        if (size <= 0)
                return  -E2BIG;

        len     = strnlen(src, size - 1);
        memcpy(dest, src, len);
        dest[len] = '\0';

        return  len;
}
```

Note: I prefer `ptrdiff_t` for array sizes, but you can use `size_t`/`ssize_t` as the linux version does.